# Secure connection in j2me

Tags: rest, https, java-me

I need to implement secure connection in j2me. i.e. all http calls calling rest api should be changes to https. For that, according to my understanding, we need to install a certificate in server side using tomcat. My doubt is:
1. How do we install certificate in j2me so that the rest call can be converted to https?
2. Can i use self signed certificates instead of  buying CAs like verisign and thwarte?

Comment: My conclusion is this: Its not possible with a self signed certificate